# Having trouble getting my http server to recognize and run python scripts

Tags: python, html, http, server, shebang

I've created a local address http webserver that will hopefully be able to open both HTML webpages and python scripts that create HTML webpages, but I keep getting a 501 error because I can't figure out how to get the webserver to recognize the code correctly. Another note: I'm coding on Windows, I'm not using Cygwin (I don't know anything about Cygwin, so if it's the recommended method here tips on how to get started with it would be appreciated.)

Anyways, here's what I've got.

I have created a folder in C:\ called server_test, and inside this folder is where I have been putting all my relevant HTML and python files. I've been editing my .py files in PyDev in eclipse (C:\workspace) and then copying the files over and putting them in C:\server_test.

To get my server running, I navigate to \server_test in cmd, open python, then create a webserver using HTTPServer, CGIRequestHandler, the current directory, address 127.0.0.1, and a port of my choosing (usually 9090). Once I've done this, I can go to my web browser and type in the address for one of my HTML pages and it runs perfectly fine. However, I currently have an HTML page meant to call a python script (also located in \server_test) that will create another HTML page, but I can't get it to work.

My HTML code looks like this:

```
<html>
<title>Debug Page</title>
<body
<h1>This is a test file. </h1> 
<form method=POST action="my_code_2.py">
            <P><input type=submit>
</form>
</body></html>
```

And then my 'my_code_2.py' looks like this:

```
#!C:\Python35-32\python.exe 

import cgi
import cgitb; cgitb.enable() 

print("Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n")
print('<html>')
print('<h1>')
print('<title>This is a second test.</title>')
print('</h1>')
print('</body')
print('</html>')
```

From what I've read about shebang lines, it appears Windows native doesn't support them? So how can I make sure that my computer knows it's supposed to run the code as Python? At the moment, when I press the button on my first HTML page, the page http://127.0.0.1:port/my_code_2.py is merely a white page with my python code printed on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the extension to .cgi on your python file and see if that helps. You'll probably want to use something like bottle.py or django tho if you're running python on a webserver. Bottle is easier to learn but with fewer features.

http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html

https://www.djangoproject.com/